# Word Macro that would find and create hyperlink of similar words

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word

This is the code of my macro (Macro1):

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
     Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     With Selection.Find
         .Text = "REQ"
         .Replacement.Text = ""
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = True
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=8, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:= _
    "http://www.neki.com/REQ12345678", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", _
    TextToDisplay:="REQ12345678"
End Sub
```

The code works fine finding the REQxxxxxxxx texts, but then pastes wrong TextToDisplay and wrong ending of an address. Instead of REQ12345678 in both places should be pastet the same text I copied before at: Selection.Copy.
I also have no idea, how to create a loop or something like that, so that Macro1 would be running until it reaches the end of a document.
Help me, please!

Hey, I solved the 1st problem with creating hyperlinks. Now I have to loop that "hyperlink" macro. I decided to create another macro, that would loop the first one. Here is my code:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Konec")
Application.Run MacroName:="Macro1"
Loop
End Sub
```

Macro1 works perfectly fine, but I can't figure it out how to loop it until the end of document - Until the ending bookmark...

Comment: do you know how the loops in vba work? there are some working examples how to use `.Find + Loop` in Word-VBA here in SO. Have you searched and tried any of these available solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to link selected text to similar text that appears later in the document.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
   With Selection.Find
         .Text = Selection
         .Replacement.Text = ""
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = True
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .MatchWildcards = True
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .Add Range:=Selection.Range, Name:=Selection
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
      With Selection.Find
         .Text = Selection
         .Replacement.Text = ""
         .Forward = False
         .Wrap = wdFindContinue
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = True
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .MatchWildcards = True
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:="", _
        SubAddress:=Selection, ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=Selection

End Sub
```